# Correcting portions of file names

Tags: regex, powershell

I'd first like to start off and say that I have thoroughly enjoyed reading through advice from this community and what it has to offer. I thank you in advance for taking time to read my question and any input that may be offered. I hate to ask someone else to simply write code for me, but perhaps someone can offer some techniques I may not have considered.

**Issue:**

> I've been tasked with assisting our web development staff in
>   correcting some of their outdated file/project names and aligning them to
>   their newly adopted naming standards.

**Example:**

> In numerous folder structures, we have file names such as the
>   following: 
>   
>  `Project.Name.J72e49q2F7-FileName.txt`
>   
>   
>   The text file extension is just an example. I am using to test out my function and the extension I need to change will be corrected later when I go to alter our legitimate data.

**What I looking to accomplish:**

> I know that there will always be a portion just before the hyphen with
>   a potential "unknown" number of defined characters (ie: the
>   "`J72e49q2F7`" portion). I am needing to breakout this portion of text
>   so I can change it to be all uppercase, similar to what `TOUPPER()` does. There are various other visual changes
>   to the name they want done that I've been able to solve, I am stuck
>   determining how to solve this portion.

**Findings from research I've considered using:**

> I've attempted a few methods already. My assumption is that **MAYBE**
>   REGEX can handle this, but I am extremely new to using REGEX. I also have a feeling there may be an easy method for using a `split()` command to break the text apart and piece it back together later.

**My function as of now:**

```
Function Fix-Filenames {
Param(
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
[string] $folderpath
)

##Capitalize first letter of each word
$TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -Filter *.txt | foreach { $NewName = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_); ren $_.FullName $NewName }

##Replace periods with spaces
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -Filter *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("."," ") + $_.Extension }

##Replace hyphens with space/hyphens
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -Filter *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("-"," - ") + $_.Extension }

##Correct Mid-Section of Project Names##
##??? Maybe a split string here? Maybe Regex?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is the RegEx solution you mentioned. It is surprisingly long because I just chained all of your Replace procedures one after another, and I added one to remove double spaces, just in case you run into a name like "Project - Name.As2SAS543x-FileName.txt" in which case replacing "-" with " - " would end up with double spaces.

```
Function Fix-Filenames {
Param(
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
[string] $folderpath
)

    $TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
    Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -Filter *.txt | Where {$_.BaseName -Match "(.+?\.)([^.]+?)(-.*)"} | foreach { $NewName = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($Matches[1]+$Matches[2].ToString().ToUpper()+$Matches[3])).replace("."," ").replace("-"," - ").replace("  "," ")+$_.Extension;ren $_.FullName $NewName}

}
```

Ah yes, I also only edited the BaseName, and then appended the extension onto the modified name for the rename.

**Edit:** The RegEx, and what the heck it means...

Ok, I'm not explaining *all* of RegEx, but this little bit I can probably manage. We'll start off with groups, there are three of them, and they are represented with parenthesis `( )`.

For right now, we're skipping the first group, and moving right to the second group which is what we really wanted anyway. The second group is `[^.]+?`, and I can understand why that is kind of confusing. So the square brackets are used for matching a group of characters. For example [a-e] matches a, b, c, d, and e. Simple enough of a concept. The carat means NOT, so ^. means it's looking for anything except a period. Then there's +?, and the plus means to repeat the previous match (anything that's not a period), while the question mark makes it 'non-greedy' meaning that it will match all that it can, but not more than it needs to. So it matches all the non-period characters before Group 3.

Group 3 is `-.*`. The first character is literally matching a hyphen, which for us is after the grouping of characters we want to ToUpper(), and before the FileName. Then it has `.*`. In RegEx the period matches any character except new lines (with a few exceptions, like our previously used range group). The asterisk will repeat the previous match zero or more times, so it matches any character, as many times as is needed. There's no ? after this one, so it's greedy and will keep matching until it can't, and since period matches any character (for the most part), it consumes everything to the end of the string.

Back to the first group. `.+?\.` starts off with a period again, so it matches any character. The + means that it matches 1 or more times, and the ? means it keeps matching as much as it can, but not more than it needs to. It if followed by an escaped period `\.`, so that literally matches a period. Basically this group looks for a period before group 2, and everything before that period.

So in plain text, it matches:

```
anything, followed by a period, followed by any non-period characters up to a hyphen, and anything else after that hyphen
```

Splitting that into our groups:

```
(anything, at least one character, followed by a period), (followed by any non-period characters up to) (a hyphen, and anything else after that hyphen if there even is anything)
(.+?\.)([^.]+?)(-.*)
```

Here's a link to RegEx101.com with a more visual breakdown of it that may be easier to understand. http://regex101.com/r/xF6zT2/1

Comment: Thank you, TheMadTechnician. This is a nice clean way to combine all my renames into a single efficient command (I knew I was using the rename & replace commands inefficiently). My only comment is that despite you correcting the code into a simple one-liner, I don't believe the toupper() is correct. I've tried this technique on a few other examples and I've yet to have it successful.

Comment: Ok, I updated it. Tested as working on my computer using your file name as a test case.

Comment: Yeah, I would not allow me to perform the ToUpper() as part of a Replace, but it worked fine when just combining the strings together.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was missing. Sadly, if you locked me in a room and said the only way I could leave was to figure out that RegEx syntax...I'd most likely never got out! Thank you for the suggestion and resolution!

Comment: I added a bit to try and explain the RegEx.

Comment: Again, MadTech, I thank you. Not only was your explanation easy to follow for someone that has barely seen RegEx, let alone used it; you even gave me a resource for attempting other patterns on my own. I only hope I'm able to pay it forward to someone else on a topic I may have input on.

Answer (score 1):

This should open up some options for you. Regex would definately work here but it is not required. You can use split to break up the path and put it back together as you see fit.

```
$folderpath = "C:\Temp\project"
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object{

    $parse = $_.Name.split(".-")
    $parse[2].ToUpper()
    # For the rename action you can uncomment the following
    # Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($newname + $_.extension)
}
```

Using just that one example you included i ended up with a file called `J72E49Q2F7.txt`

First `-split` the name into an array. We will split on `.` and `-`. Not the sequence of characters. Then we take the item in position 2 which would be the string of chracters you are looking for. The `toUpper()` will set it to uppercase. You can use that to rename the files if you wish.

**Note**: This solution is dependant on your files following this structure `Project.Name.SOMETHINGRANDOM-FileName.txt` more importantly that they start with `Project.Name.`. If this is not the case regex might be a better fit or more logic will need to be added.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I will take your suggestions in to consideration. I feel this might give me other options depending on the team's needs.